# Clojure: Functional way to manipulate Scene Graph

Tags: clojure

### Context

I'm dealing with a large, nested, structured document, which shows up on the screen as a scene graph. The user needs to have the ability to modify this document -- which I am currently using functional zippers to implement.

Now, currently, I'm redrawing the entire document after every change. However, when the use of a scene graph, I would only need to modify the part that changes.

However (without intending to start a flamewar), I'm increasingly starting to feel that this problem is fundamentally a problem about state, not functions. In particular:

- user actions (up, down, left, right, insert char, delete char) are about manipulating state, not doing calculations
- there's only one copy of the document at once, it's only hit by one thread, and there's no gain for sharing

### Current Approach

I use functional zippers to store the document and to provide state manipulation functions. Then, I continuously redraw.

### Solution I suspect might be correct:

Store everything in a scene graph, ditch function zippers, and after modification, directly modify the part of the scene graph that changes.

### Technical Question:

Have others dealt with this? Is there a technical, formal name for this problem? (Equiv of "Dining Philosophers" in concurrency?) Is there a well established solution to this problem?

### Disclaimer

This question is a bit soft. I can't paste a code example of minimal broken case since

```
* my code is around 5K LOC
* it's not for me to share publicly
```

However, this is a real technical solution, and I hope others can share their answers

Thanks!

Comment: your user number is prime! awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fundamental process sounds fine. It is flexible in it's current form because you have the option of having a separate thread update the tree for instance and you can implement an "undo" button rather trivially. If after each modification you **return both the new tree and the path to the part that changed** you could then update only the part that changed in the display. Lots of people have stronger opinions than me on separating "models" and "views" though I suspect that at least some of their wisdom applies here.